# grep en varias lineas Bash

Tags: linux, bash, grep

Quiero encontrar varias líneas dentro de un archivo.

Si tengo 3 líneas no me da problemas porque uso lo siguiente para mostrar la última línea y las 2 anteriores:

```
grep -B 2 "lo que busco"
```

Pero mi duda es: ¿qué pasa cuando quiero buscar la primera línea, la del medio y la del final? Esto es a modo de ejemplo, ya que pueden estar en cualquier ubicación.

¿Debo concatenar o usar un && con un grep?

He intentado por ejemplo

```
cat archivo.txt | grep -i "primera busqueda" | grep -i "segunda busqueda" > busqueda.txt
```

y así, pero no me funciona.

Comment: No está claro lo que preguntas, Fabian. Danos un [mcve] con un fichero ejemplo y qué querrías que fuera la salida. No queda claro si quieres buscar un patrón distintas veces o bien un patrón y unas líneas en función de su posición.

Answer (score 0):

Si he entendio correctamente, lo que quieres es un número indeterminado de líneas que contengan alguno de los contenidos que buscas.

Para ello debes usar la opción [`-e`](https://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/grep.html#Matching-Control) del grep. Esta opción te permite buscar varios elementos distintos:

```
cat archivo.txt | grep -ie "primera busqueda" -e "segunda busqueda" > busqueda.txt
```

Por cada string que quieras buscar tienes que ponerle un `-e`

Al hacer dos pipes buscas "segunda busqueda" en en resultado de buscar "primera linea".

También puedes quitarte el cat si quieres:

```
grep -ie "primera busqueda" -e "segunda busqueda" archivo1.txt archivo2.txt > busqueda.txt
```